# Master and child DML insert not working

Tags: apex, master-detail, insert

I try to insert master and child simultaneously, however, it is not working:

```
   public PageReference Submit() {
     try {
        insert objectSelected;

        Id objectSelectedId = objectSelected.Id;

        List<Participant__c> grpart = new List<Participant__c>(listSelectedParticipants);
        for (ParticipantsWrapper wrap : wrappers){
            wrap.participant.MasterObjectId = objectSelectedId;
            grpart.add(wrap.participant);
        }

        insert grpart;


    }   
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception occurred '+String.valueOf(e));
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }
    PageReference pageRef_save = new PageReference('/apex/HP');
    pageRef_save.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef_save;
}
```

What is wrong here? The `objectSelected` record does get inserted.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include the entire `submit` method.

Comment: The insert may be failing by throwing a `DmlException` which will provide an explanation of e.g. failed validation that is blocking the insert.

Comment: I had a general exception and it did not throw anything.

Comment: Well what was the exact message / text of the exception I fail to understand when an exception or message is given why it is not included in the question and we are expected to guess

Comment: And how are you constructing the objectselected.

Comment: Well, like this: objectSelected = new sobject__c(); 
but as said, that is not the problem as that gets inserted. I am not sure though if the ID objectSelectedId gets recognised all right.

Comment: @user40501 When you have information to add, please **[edit]** your post to do so. Comments are often easy to miss and may be deleted.

Comment: You should `return null` at the end of your catch block and make sure you rerender an `<apex:pageMessages>` tag on your front end if you actually want to see the error.

Comment: :-D Invalid Email Error. Thank you, Adrian!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return null at the end of your catch block and make sure you rerender an  tag on your front end if you actually want to see the error. Here is a common pattern:

**Controller**

```
public PageReference performSomeOperation()
{
    try
    {
        // perform operation
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(d);
        return null;
    }
    // return success redirect
}
```

**Markup**

```
<apex:page ...>
    <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
    <!-- intermediate markup -->
        <apex:commandButton action="{!performSomeOperation}" rerender="msgs" value="..." />
    <!-- intermediate markup -->
</apex:page>
```